# What is the best way to shield the report parameters carried in the URL query string while using Reporting Services URL access?

Tags: reporting-services, url-rewriting, reporting

I've a report server which has the SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) installed. The report server provides URL access as the interface for other web/win applications to interact with. Since URL access is used, all report parameters will be carried in the query string of the URL. The problem is that, if there are parameters which carry privacy information, those privacy information will be easily exposed.

Please advise the best way to shield the report parameters. Further, is it possible to use the URL rewriting in the SSRS?

Thanks & regards,
William

Comment: Is the parent application just calling the actual SSRS Report Manager via URL?  IE: I click on a button in a WinForms/ASP.NET application and I am taken to http://myreportserver/Reports/myreport&param1=value ??

You might wan to consider wrapping the reports in the report viewer control, where you will be able to hide the passed value more easily.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: Yes, I finally wrap the report viewer into an ASP.net page. Why don't you leave your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented such requirement by embedding the reporting services into a modal window in an ASP.Net page, then force the method of user-parameter-passing to POST. Further protection can be achieved by enabling HTTPS.